# How did the Enterprise crew learn of Guinan's ability to perceive nonlinear time?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the ST:TNG episode, *[Yesterday's Enterprise](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Yesterday%27s_Enterprise)*, Data says that Guinan's species has a perception which goes beyond linear time. **Why would Data in the alternate timeline think that?**

Back in the main timeline, when Guinan was ripped from the Nexus in "Generations", part of her was still left there. She told Picard she couldn't go back with him because she was already there. The part of her left in the Nexus, a place where time had no meaning, gave her her sixth sense. This explanation was in the original Generations script but was later edited.

> GUINAN : It took a long time, but eventually I learned to live with it. And I began to realize that my experience in the Nexus had changed me...I knew things about people...about events...about time...
>
> PICARD : Your "sixth sense"... I've always wondered where it came from

From this, one could think her abilities are not a feature of her species, but of her personally. It seems the Nexus gave her and a handful of other El-Aurian refugees have the ability to perceive time differently.

In addition to the Generations movie, the novel, *[Engines of Destiny](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Engines_of_Destiny)*, also makes it clear that Guinan's abilities are due to the Nexus.

**Yet, how did the Enterprise crew in the alternate timeline know?** Was Guinan involved in some temporal exchange before they encountered the Enterprise-C? And that somehow in that prior event, they became aware of Guinan having an extraordinary power?

If they didn't know, they would never have trusted her advice to send the Enterprise-C crew back through the temporal rift. Please don't tell me that Picard was willing to send them back because one more ship would not have saved the Federation from surrender, but the sacrifice of a single ship long ago would have. He decided to send them back *before* Data mentioned that the Enterprise-C's sacrifice would convince them to negotiate with the Federation for peace. Picard never would have sacrificed 125 lives solely on intuition. He would have let them live out their days in the current timeline. Unless he *knew from experience* to trust her.

To be clear, I am not asking why Picard and the Enterprise-D crew sent the Enterprise-C back in time. I am only asking how the Enterprise-D learned of Guinan's abilities.

Comment: you post the answer in your question. Guinan told Picard.

Comment: You misquoted Data. He actually says "Perhaps her species has a perception that goes beyond linear time." He says this after Geordi asks how Guinan could know that the timeline has been altered.

Comment: @DTagliaferri Not quite! Guinan's said that in the **main** timeline, not the **alternate** timeline. The question is how does the crew in the alternate timeline know? I updated my post to make that more clear.

Comment: That line in Generations was a retcon anyway. Years previous, Q implied she was some sort of powerful extra-dimensional creature of whom he had reason to be afraid.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Add to that that the events in "Time's Arrow" have established that Guinan, even before encountering the Nexus (thus this probably *is* a feature of her species) is very long-lived by human standards.

Comment: "Picard never would have sacrificed 125 lives solely on intuition. He would have let them live out their days in the current timeline." - remember that the Federation was horribly losing the war with the Klingon Empire in the alternate timeline, so Picard was faced with a dilemma: in this timeline they don't stand much of a chance at life anyway and would have no good honors or memorial, but in the other timeline, they would be remembered for what they did even if it meant death, it would be honorable and would most certainly mean no war took place. The choice was clear, albeit hard, for him.

Answer (score 11):

**The whole point of the plot of Yesterday's Enterprise was that the crew *didn't know* if Guinan was right, but had to do what needed to be done on trust.**

As stated in the comments on your question, Data is actually guessing that El-Aurians have time-space perceptions, as a way to explain her perceptions.  It's clear during the conversation that the crew are open to the idea that she might have such a power, so it's possible that the altered timeline's past does indeed contain Guinan doing "Guinany" things.

There's multiple factors involved in sending the Enterprise-C back in time:

1. One thing they DO know is that the ship has travelled forward in time.
2. They also know that the Klingons "blame" the Federation for NOT coming to their aid at Niranda 3, one of the many triggers to the war they are fighting.
3. Captain Garrett states, however, that they DID arrive at Narendra III before the temporal anomaly, so the crew can surmise that the reasons the Klingons are angry is because the Enterprise-C was thrown out of time.
4. **Picard states that the war is going very badly for the Federation.**  They're seriously excited about the fact that they might be able to monkey-patch the Enterprise-C into a fighting machine for the new war despite it's already extensive damage.  Starfleet expects to have to surrender in less than six months.
5. War is an unnatural state for the Federation.  This isn't an alternate timeline where Spock has a beard;  it's a timeline with a divergence just a few decades "ago."  Picard would be willing to believe that the war they are in is an anomaly.
6. Garrett states that much of her crew wants to go back anyway, as this future doesn't contain their loved ones, and others don't like "sneaking out from a fight."  The only reason they'd stay is to fight the Klingons.
7. Picard's closing argument to Garrett that one ship now won't make a  difference but a ship at Narendra III might shows that even he thinks it's a long shot, but that it's better than surrender.

So, **Guinan's intuition was not the *only* reason for sending the Enterprise-C back.**  It was definitely the *catalyst,* and her absolute conviction that time has changed, and that Tasha Yar should be dead, certainly gave stronger weight to the idea that the Enterprise-C should go back.  The episode implies that nobody else had even thought to check to see if the Enterprise-C should be sent back until she mentioned it to them.  So her intuition was important in starting the argument.

But, despite the high esteem you give Picard, **he most certainly would send 125 lives on a suicide mission if he thought it would save the Federation.**  As he says to Garrett, the Federation has only 6 months of life left, and the Klingons aren't going to be pleasant masters.  That's what convinces **Picard,** but, remember, he's only a Captain, and so is Garrett (with a few extra decades of seniority.)  While technically Starfleet regulations state that, as Captain of the tactically superior ship, Picard could "order" the Enterprise-C back through the rift, it's still up to Garrett to "make it so".  Garrett, seeing the state of the Federation and knowing she has a chance to save it, essentially *volunteers* for the suicide mission.

Comment: Actually, Starfleet regulations state that in combat scenarios involving multiple captains of equal rank, the captain of the vessel with tactical superiority is in command. Therefore Picard can order Garrett into the rift if he chooses.

Comment: Well, true, but that doesn't mean Garrett has to do it, @KevinLaity :D  But you're right, I forgot about that quirk of Starfleet regs.

Comment: @ZoeyBoles "*... the crew can surmise that the reasons the Klingons are angry is because the Enterprise-C was thrown out of time.*" Not quite. :-) **The Klingons at Narendra 3 may have no idea the Enterprise-C was thrown forward in time.** They were probably ready to go to war over something else, and the sacrifice of the Enterprise-C convinced them a peace deal with the Federation was worthwhile.

Comment: @ZoeyBoles "*They also know that the Klingons "blame" the Federation for NOT coming to their aid at Niranda 3, one of the many triggers to the war they are fighting.*" You got that backwards. The Klingons didn't blame them for not coming to aid in the alternate timeline. It's just that the Klingons in the main timeline believe the Federation is honorable because the Enterprise-C did come to their aid.

Comment: @ZoeyBoles I still don't think Picard would have sent 125 people to their deaths based on intuition or trust in Guinan. He might gamble that risking 125 on a suicide mission was worth saving 40 billion lives from a 22 year long war, but that's a calculated rational gamble, not a decision based on intuition. Even if the mission is a long shot, the payoff is worth the gamble. Very different from intuition. Picard is a rational mind.

Comment: @RichS What I meant was that the Enterprise-C was the "prop" that held together the Khitomer accords and various peace hopes, opening the door to the Federation-as-we-know-it, but you are probably right that they didn't know.  I have to say "Probably," though, because the Enterprise-C was *actually in combat* and *almost already destroyed* when they disappeared. I'm sure SOMEBODY in Klingon space must have noticed a Federation ship answer the distress call and start combat...

Comment: @RichS ...only to disappear suddenly like cowards.  Remember, Niranda 3 falls either way;  the Klingons respect for the Enterprise-C was fighting *to the death* to save a *frenemy colony* that not even the *Klingon Defense Fleet was going to bother with.* It was this respect from the Klingons, garnered from their warrior culture, that had the impact of the Enterprise-C.  Coming in, tossing a few torpedoes and running away?  That's what COWARDS do.

Comment: @RichS Finally, I would like to respectfully point out the scale of the disaster the Enterprise-C may resolve with their suicide mission. The Federation, millions of worlds, the freedoms it brings, and the billions or trillions of people who will be killed during occupation hang on this mission. Countries and commanders have sent people on suicide missions for less weighty objectives. The crew of the Enterprise-C are a drop in the cosmic bucket compared to the war they might resolve.  Guinan's intuition started the fire, but Picard is driven by the brutal realism of war. See: Forlorn hope.

Comment: @ZoeyBoles Do you have any citations for how the Klingons at Narendra 3 saw the actions of Enterprise-C?

Comment: @RichS ... the episode's dialogue?

PICARD
I think I know your opinion, Commander. This is a briefing. I'm not seeking your consent.

RIKER
With all due respect, Captain, we'd be asking one hundred and twenty-five people to die a meaningless death.

DATA
Not necessarily meaningless, Commander. Klingons place honor
above all else. If the crew of the Enterprise-C had died fighting for the survival of a Klingon outpost, that would have been considered a meaningful act of honor by the Klingon Empire.

PICARD
Even their deaths... might have prevented the war.

Comment: Late to the debate here, but there's a couple of factors not mentioned (IMO): After years of brutal war Captain Picard of the battleship Enterprise-D is obviously a sterner hard-ass than his mainline counterpart.  If strategic value might be gained, he'd order a military asset like Enterprise-C to a suicide mission.  Not callously or cruelly, but like a necessary chess move.  Secondly, I'm not sure why Guinan's abilities would be such a mystery.  She's been on Battleship Enterprise-D for years and we have no idea what shenanigans/adventures/relationships might have taken place to "expose" her.

Comment: @Blaze, both good points.  Picard in Yesterday's Enterprise never even struck me as that much different, nor did anyone else.  The difference was the circumstances.  Unlike "Mirror, Mirror" episodes, these aren't evil versions of these characters, but just extremely stressed out versions in unfortunate situations.  So Picard acted like Picard.  With that said, I think part of the idea is that temporal shenanigans are exploration fun plots, not survival phaser plots, and the liklihood that the flagship was off exploring temporal nostrils and therefore triggering Guinan would be pretty low.

Comment: @Zoey Boles 7. From his lonely “throne” of a captain’s chair to the way he shut down further discussions (ie Riker) with a decisive, curt order were indicators to me that the Battleship Enterprise was a less democratic, seriously military ship. This Picard never enjoyed kiddie drawings on “Picard Day”. Again, not nasty or cruel-just strict and commanding.

Comment: @Zoey Boles 7. As to the other aspect, I would say the majority of events involving the Starship Enterprise required zero action on their part. Astounding Events just happened without warning. Time rifts, omnipotent beings popping in, super alien probes, etc etc.  I don’t think Astounding Events would spare the Battleship Enterprise just because they only want to be soldiers. And in some of these unknown AE’s, people may have gotten a sense Guinan was more than a cool bartender